# Configure htaccess to directly access CSS and JS files but redirect all the other requests to index file

Tags: javascript, php, css, apache, .htaccess

I am currently developing a system but I am positively confused as to how I am supposed to implement this. This is my simplified file structure

```
-.htaccess
--/public
--/public/index.php
--/project
--/project/template1/css
--/project/template2/js
--/project/all-other-files-and-folders-used
```

My system currently redirects all requests to the index.php, which loads the files in the project folder for all other work BUT I want the htaccess to recognize all the CSS,IMG and JS files in the Project folders and allow direct access to them.

This is the .htaccess file that I have now

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^((?!public/).*)$ public/$1 [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?cmd=$1 [PT,L]
```

Is this possible?
Thanks in advance

Comment: This condition: "RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f" must be protecting you from redirecting the files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^((?!(?:public|project)/).+)$ public/index.php?cmd=$1  [QSA,NC,L]
```

Comment: Would you mind explaining your code so that I can better understand what is happening? Ive implemented your solution but it only works partly its preventing my other php files from being accessed

Comment: Where are other php files located? This rule will only affect non-files and non-directories

Comment: They are located in the project folder indicated in my simplified file structure above.

Comment: Also try my updated rule.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it has worked